# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded is not valid when using multiparts, it must start with "multipart/"

Tags: apache-servicemix

code in processor:

```
Response response = RestAssured.given().header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                    .formParam("request", request1).request().post(url);
```

`url` mentioned here is external email outbound service in Apache ServiceMix
I'm using just simple maven project to invoke ServiceMix email service

The above code working fine. But I need to send attachment with the above POST request. So I add one more functionality like as:

```
Response response = RestAssured.given().header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                    .formParam("request", request1).multiPart(fileName , fileName + "bin",
attachment).request().post(url);
```

It shows some error like below:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded is not valid when using multiparts, it must start with "multipart/".
```

Comment: The Content-Type for multiparts as per specification should be multipart/form-data

Comment: Even I'm using Content-Type as "multipart/form-data" but the request not sent to ServiceMix Server